# Synchronise BlueStack and Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, bluestacks

In my developement I use Bluestack app to test my android application , so my great problem is every time when I build my code and test it Bluestack reinstalls my .apk again which blocked my Eclipse ....... so I want to find how we can synchronise Eclipse and Bluestack without restarting my Eclipse !

Thanks ;)

Comment: Development questions are off topic here. Please read the FAQ.

Comment: Why don't you just use the Android emulator?

Comment: Using Android Emulator make my tests so slow that 's why I take BlueStack like alternative solution .

Comment: @Phenix_dz While creating emulator select cpu Intel x86 Atom for faster emulater (intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager)